# Nuxt / Vue JS - Writing a HTML template for a markdown file

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs, changelog

I have a Markdown file which contains release notes. For example:

```
## 1.0.0

### New
#### Added new language support

### Fixed
#### This is fixed
#### This is fixed

### Changed
#### Something changed

### Feature
#### New Feature Added

## 2.0.0

### New
#### Added new language support
```

In my HTML, I would like loop over the release notes for all new releases. I have queried the document in the page like so:

```html
<template>
    <changelog :article="article"/> 
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import Vue from "vue";
  export default Vue.extend({
    async asyncData({ $content }) {
      const article = await $content("changelogs/iOS/changelog").fetch();
      return { article };
    },  
    watchQuery: true,
  });
</script>
```

In my component, I have:

```html
<template>
    <article :document="article">
</template>
```

I would like the result to be something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parse result of the content is stored in `article.body.children[]`. Each child contains the following node data:

- `tag` - HTML tag (e.g., `h2`, `h3`)
- `type` - Element type (e.g., `element`, `text`)
- `value` - Element value (the text contents)
- `props` - Extra props data, including `id`
- `children[]` - Child nodes

You could use that info to parse the nodes into a convenient data structure that stores release info, such as:

- `title` from the `text` child of `h2`
- `id` from `props` of `h2`
- `changes[]` to hold the change lines, each containing:

  - `id` from `props` of `h4`
  - `type` from the `text` child of `h3`
  - `text` from the `text` child of `h4`

```js
const elems = article.body.children.filter(node => node.type === 'element')
let rel = {}
let type = ''
for (const node of elems) {
  if (node.tag === 'h2') {
    rel = {
      id: node.props.id,
      title: node.children.find(c => c.type === 'text').value,
      changes: []
    }
    this.releases.push(rel)

  } else if (node.tag === 'h3') {
    type = node.children.find(c => c.type === 'text').value

  } else if (node.tag === 'h4') {
    rel.changes.push({
      id: node.props.id,
      type,
      text: node.children.find(c => c.type === 'text').value,
    })
  }
}
```

Then, use `v-for` to render the list of release info parsed above.

```html
<article v-for="rel of releases" :key="rel.id">
  <h3 class="title">{{ rel.title }}</h3>
  <section class="change" v-for="change in rel.changes" :key="change.id">
    <div class="type" :class="change.type">{{ change.type }}</div>
    <div class="text">{{ change.text }}</div>
  </section>
</article>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/reformatting-nuxt-content-markdown-20r7e?file=/src/components/Changelog.vue)